# Flex: Make the item center aligned if only one div is visible

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with two elements inside.
I want both elements to sit on ends of the corner.
So I used [display: flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) with [justify-content: space-between](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp).
But if one of the element is hidden, the other element should align center rather than left align.

```js
function showHide() {
  var el = document.getElementById('firstEl'),
    elStyle = el.style,
    elDisplay = elStyle.display;
  elStyle.display = elDisplay != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="firstEl" class="first-element">one</div>
  <div class="secondelement">second</div>
</div>

<button onclick="showHide()">show/hide</button>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugb3nwc0/

Comment: `flex-direction: row;` is not required. Default value for `flex-direction` is `row`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use justify-content: space-between;**

Instead align them using the `margin` property.

> margin-left:auto : right aligns a flex child item
>
> margin-right:auto : left aligns a flex child item

```js
function showHide() {
  var el = document.getElementById('firstEl'),
    elStyle = el.style,
    elDisplay = elStyle.display;
  elStyle.display = elDisplay != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first-element {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="firstEl" class="first-element">one</div>
  <div class="secondelement">second</div>
</div>

<button onclick="showHide()">show/hide</button>
```

Comment: Second element is not positioning to center.

Comment: Welcome  :) @VinodGubbala